# What's the most efficient way to do these two foreach-loops?

Tags: linq-to-sql, .net-3.5, foreach

i'm not sure this is the best way to do the following code. I'm not sold on a foreach inside another foreach. Could this be done *better** with Linq?

*I understand that better could be either
a) more performant
b) easier to read / more elegant
c) all of the above

NOTE: .NET 3.5 solutions accepted :)
NOTE2: the two IList's were the results of a multi-recordset stored procedure, via Linq2Sql.

here's the make believe code:

```
// These two lists are the results from a IMultipleResults Linq2Sql stored procedure.
IList<Car> carList = results.GetResult<Car>().ToList();
IList<Person> people = results.GetResult<Person>().ToList();

// Associate which people own which cars.
foreach(var person in people)
{
    var cars = (from c in cars
                where c.CarId == person.CarId
                select c).ToList();

    foreach (var car in cars)
    {
        car.Person = person;    
    }
}
```

Cheers :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think performance would be any different but if you're looking for terseness:

```
var q = from person in people
        join car in cars on person.CarId equals car.CarId
        select new { car, person };
foreach(var o in q)
{
  o.car.Person = o.person; 
}
```

Edit: After Jon's hint on this version being faster I got curious and profiled both functions. This version seems twice as fast which is amazing. I checked the disassembly. The overhead of the original implementation seems to come from new enumerators getting created for both outer and inner loop, causing P times new/dispose overhead.

For this code only one Enumerator is created which I think is the magic of "Join" function. I didn't examine how it works though.

Comment: I believe this *will* perform better, as it will be using a hashtable inside the join - the complexity will be O(P+C) instead of O(P*C) I *think*.

Comment: Jon it seems it's really faster. It looks like you're right in O(P+C) vs O(P*C) thing since this version creates a single enumerator after join runs while original works with two outer/inner enumerators. I added my findings to the answer.

Comment: Oh guys -- one more question on this. Could this answer be updated to be an extension method (or at least a static method?)

Comment: to make it more generic, if possible. it's a really kewl little bit of code and i was wondering if it could be possible to do somethign like that. maybe not.

Comment: If you make your code generic, I'll make mine. Otherwise answer and question don't correlate.

Comment: @Jon, you are the man.  It is amazing that there are people who knows these kinds of things off the top of their heads.